# How to get a block of text on same X axis coordinate [Google Cloud Vision API]

Tags: android, machine-learning, ocr, google-cloud-vision

So I am trying to implement a personal project in Android where you can scan different receipts from shopping centers. I want to come up with a module which helps the manual input of users a little bit, by automating as much of the activity. Situation is:

1. I would like to fetch the total of the receipt, knowing that as a standard, it can be found on a line like this: TOTAL........... 33.9 Currency. How can I actually get the blocks which are on same axis with the block containing "Total"?
2. Same thing applies for each individual product, I would like to take the values of each individual cart product and it's value and put it in an Edit Text in Android, so the user can do the final re-touching.

Example receipt:

[Shopping receipt from Mega Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XccqM.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not have support for my language. Thus, the results are not really accurate :/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a project idea instead of coding questions.

One thing I suggest is to guess the blocks from the relative location of bounding boxes.

It is a challenging research problem though. Perhaps Vision API will open some feature for customers to directly understand receipts.

Answer (score 0):

To get text line by line you need to setup a custom logic that would process lines based on the symbols returned by Google Vision API, which could go along the lines of the following steps:

1. Create a collection of all the symbols returned in a `TextAnnotation`
2. Iterate through the collection and create a line `string` based on checking the first symbol's X coordinate which is `givenSymbol.BoundingBox.Vertices[2].X` against all the other symbols X coordinates.
3. Implement checks to skip already processed words and think about implementing an X offset, that would check if a given X coordinate is close enough to the one you're checking against, to account for a slightly tilted input text.